# Properties and physical meaning of disjointness of reducible representations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, representation-theory, density-operator

I have the following doubt. Let's assume we have two mixed states $\rho_1 = \Sigma_i a_i \omega_i^{1}$ and $\rho_2 = \Sigma_i b_i \omega_i^{2}$ on the same algebra, where the states $\omega$ are all pure states and $\Sigma_i a_i = \Sigma_i b_i = 1$.

1. Could it be that the two mixed states $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are disjoint? (By disjoint, I mean that the GNS,  Gelfand–Naimark–Segal,   representations for $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are not quasi-equivalent) despite that for each pure state $i$ there is a unitary map $U_i$ such that $U_i \pi_{\omega_i^{1}} (A) U_i^{\dagger} = \pi_{\omega_i^{2}} (A), \forall A$ in the algebra.)
2. What is the physical meaning if two mixed states are disjoint?

**Example:** I think that a possible example could be the case where $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are two KMS states. If there are a finite number of degrees of freedom the two representations are equivalent, but I think that the case of interest here is only with infinite number of degrees of freedom. For example, it has been proved that two KMS states with different temperatures are disjoint (please see Takesaki work for more details: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01649582). I would like to understand what does it mean from both mathematical and physical points of view